# How to set border-shadow in migradoc?

Tags: c#, pdfsharp, migradoc

```
MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Tables.Row myRow= myTable.AddRow();

            //Fila Titulo
            MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Paragraph paraTitle= myRow[0].AddParagraph("Some text");
            paraTitulo.Format.Alignment = MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.ParagraphAlignment.Center;
            myRow.Format.Font.Size = 11;
            myRow.Format.Font.Bold = true;
            myRow.TopPadding = 3;
            myRow.BottomPadding = 2;
            myRow.Format.Borders.Bottom.Width = 2.5;
            myRow.Format.Borders.Right.Visible = false;
            myRow.Format.Borders.Left.Visible = false;
            myRow.Format.Borders.Top.Visible = false;
            myRow.Format.Borders.Color = MigraDoc.DocumentObjectModel.Colors.LightBlue;
```

Answer (score 0):

Border shadows are not implemented in MigraDoc.

You could add a dummy column to the right and a dummy row at the bottom and use those to draw a shadow yourself. This will look good only if the table fits on a single page.

Comment: Thanks! But can you give me an example for that?